# Compare two primitive long variables in java

Tags: java, compare, long-integer

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I'm moving from C# to Java. I have an object and a getter method which returns its  ID. I want to compare the ids of two objects of the same type and check if the values of their ids are equal.

tried:

```
obj.getId() == obj1.getId();
```

---

```
Long id1 = obj.getId();
Long id2 = obj1.getId();

assertTrue(id1.equals(id2))
```

---

```
assertTrue(id1== id2)
```

Comment: Actually this question is confusing because it is not about comparing, but about testing for equality. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

Comment: you are not trying to compare two primitive longs You are trying to compare two boxed Long.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In java:

- the `==` operator tells you if the two operands are the *same* object (instance).
- the `.equals()` method on `Long` tells you if they are *equal in value*.

But you shouldn't do either. The correct way to do it is this:

```
assertEquals(id1, id2);
```

With `assertEquals()`, if the assertion fails, the error message will tell you what the two values were, eg `expected 2, but was 5` etc

Answer (score 6):

To compare two primitive long you can simply use ==

Example:

```
long x = 1L;
long y = 1L;

if (x == y) {
 System.out.println("value of x and y are same");
}
```

To compare two Long objects you can use Long.compare(long x, long y). This method was added in java 1.7. Below is the method implementation:

```
public static int compare(long x, long y) {
        return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Example:

```
Long x = new Long(1);
Long y = new Long(1);
if (Long.compare(x,y) == 0) {
  System.out.println(values of x and y are same);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in java,

use `==` to compare primitives and `x.equals(y)` to compare objects.

I'm not sure what your question is-- it looks like you tried both, and did neither work?

Note, you are using `Long` instead of `long`, so you want to use `.equals()`

(`long` is a primitive, `Long` is an object)

Comment: Thank you! I was comparing the modified dates of two files that should have been the same (because one was set to the other,) but == was always failing, even though when I set breakpoints and checked them, they were identical. Turns out my mistake was the capital L in "Long jFileTime = jFile.lastModified();"... replaced it with a lowercase l and suddenly my == comparison started working. Really annoying that it doesn't give any compiler warning about how I have an implied, non-explicit cast occurring...

Answer (score 2):

Try doing the following:

```
assertTrue(id1.longValue() == id2.longValue())
```

Answer (score 2):

They must not be equal using ==. Use either:

```
id1.equals(id2)
```

or

```
id1.longValue() == id2.longValue()
```

In both cases I left out null-checks because I doubt you'd forget them, if they were needed here ;)

So, why is Long not always == another Long with the same value? The answer is easy. They're different objects! Depending on *how* the Long was retrieved they might be the same, because of internal caching. See [Long.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28long%29).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the comments about the right comparison, strong typing can help you resolve your issue.

Does getID() return something of type Long (that's a class type) or of type long (that's a primitive type)? The problem is that if the method returns a primitive value, then comparing with '==' and 'equals()' will both work, because Java automatically casts primitives into wrapper objects when you need them.

But the other way, if getID() returns a Long value, comparing with '==' is likely to fail, because that checks if you have the same object, not if the objects have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of the difference between `Long` and `long` - `long` is the primitive type, `Long` is the wrapper type. (A bit like a boxed value in C#, but strongly typed.) What's the return type of `getId()`?

Simply:

```
assertEqual(id1, id2);
```

should be fine if you're doing this in a test. Otherwise, you could use:

```
if (id1.equals(ids2))
```

if they're definitely *not* null, or use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
if (Objects.equal(id1, id2))
```

to handle nullity. (You can write [`Objects.equal`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) yourself, of course, but you should definitely get hold of Guava *anyway*, so you might as well use that...)

It's worth noting that certain wrapper objects are reused - so for example:

```
// This will work
Long x = 5L;
Long y = 5L;
assertTrue(x == y); // Reference comparison

// This *probably* won't but it could!
x = 10000L;
y = 10000L;
assertTrue(x == y); // Reference comparison
```

Comment: The assertTrue statement won't work with larger values above 127. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541636/comparing-boxed-long-values-127-and-128

Comment: @LyleZ: Won't is too strong an assertion. It might, it just isn't guaranteed to.