# Comparing boxed Long values 127 and 128

Tags: java, comparison, autoboxing

I want to compare two **Long** objects values using `if` conditions. When these values are **less than 128**, the `if` condition works properly, but when they are **greater than or equal to 128**, comparison fails.

Example:

```
Long num1 = 127;
Long num2 = 127;

if (num1 == num2) {
    // Works ok
}
```

Comparison on the code above works properly, but fails in the code below:

```
Long num1 = 128;
Long num2 = 128;

if (num1 == num2) {
    // Does NOT work
}
```

Why is there a problem in comparing **Long** variables with values *greater than 127*? If the variables data types are changed to **long primitives**, then the comparisons work for all cases.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Java caches boxed Integer instances from `-128` to `127`. Since you are using `==` to compare objects *references* instead of *values*, only cached objects will match. Either work with `long` unboxed primitive values or use `.equals()` to compare your `Long` objects.

**Long (pun intended) version**

> Why there is problem in comparing Long variable with value greater than 127? If the data type of above variable is primitive (long) then code work for all values.

**[Java caches Integer objects instances from the range -128 to 127](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/boxing_and_caches_integer_valueof)**. That said:

- If you set to N Long variables the value `127` (*cached*), the same object instance will be pointed by all references. (N variables, 1 instance)
- If you set to N Long variables the value `128` (*not cached*), you will have an object instance pointed by every reference. (N variables, N instances)

That's why this:

```
Long val1 = 127L;
Long val2 = 127L;

System.out.println(val1 == val2);

Long val3 = 128L;
Long val4 = 128L;

System.out.println(val3 == val4);
```

Outputs this:

> true
>   false

For the **127L** value, since both references (val1 and val2) point to the same object instance in memory (cached), it returns `true`.

On the other hand, for the **128** value, since there is no instance for it cached in memory, a new one is created for any new assignments for boxed values, resulting in two different instances (pointed by val3 and val4) and returning `false` on the comparison between them.

That happens solely because you are comparing two `Long` **object references**, not `long` primitive values, with the `==` operator. If it wasn't for this Cache mechanism, these comparisons would **always** fail, so the real problem here is comparing boxed values with `==` operator.

Changing these variables to primitive `long` types will prevent this from happening, but in case you need to keep your code using `Long` objects, you can safely make these comparisons with the following approaches:

```
System.out.println(val3.equals(val4));                     // true
System.out.println(val3.longValue() == val4.longValue());  // true
System.out.println((long)val3 == (long)val4);              // true
```

(Proper null checking is necessary, even for castings)

**IMO**, it's always a good idea to stick with **.equals()** methods when dealing with Object comparisons.

Reference links:

- https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/03/24/autoboxing.html
- https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/boxing_and_caches_integer_valueof
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/surprising-results-autoboxing

Answer (score 15):

`num1` and `num2` are Long objects.  You should be using `equals()` to compare them.  `==` comparison might work sometimes because of the way JVM boxes primitives, but don't depend on it.

```
if (num1.equals(num1))
{
 //code
}
```

Comment: This (which is better), or compare the return value of `.longValue()`.

Answer (score 15):

Java caches the primitive values from **-128 to 127**. When we compare two **Long** objects java internally type cast it to primitive value and compare it. But above 127 the Long object will not get type caste. Java caches the output by **.valueOf()** method.

This caching works for Byte, Short, Long from -128 to 127.
For Integer caching works From -128 to java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high or 127, whichever is bigger.(We can set top level value upto which Integer values should get cached by using java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high).

```
 For example:
    If we set java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=500;
    then values from -128 to 500 will get cached and 

    Integer a=498;
    Integer b=499;
    System.out.println(a==b)

    Output will be "true".
```

***Float and Double objects never gets cached.***

**Character will get cache from 0 to 127**

You are comparing two objects. so **==** operator will check equality of object references. There are following ways to do it.

1) type cast both objects into primitive values and compare

```
    (long)val3 == (long)val4
```

2) read value of object and compare

```
    val3.longValue() == val4.longValue()
```

3) Use equals() method on object comparison.

```
    val3.equals(val4);
```

Answer (score 4):

Comparing non-primitives (aka Objects) in Java with `==` compares their reference instead of their values. `Long` is a class and thus `Long` values are Objects.

The problem is that the Java Developers wanted people to use `Long` like they used `long` to provide compatibility, which led to the concept of autoboxing, which is essentially the feature, that `long`-values will be changed to `Long`-Objects and vice versa as needed. The behaviour of autoboxing is not exactly predictable all the time though, as it is not completely specified.

So to be safe and to have predictable results always use `.equals()` to compare objects and do not rely on autoboxing in this case:

```
Long num1 = 127, num2 = 127;
if(num1.equals(num2)) { iWillBeExecutedAlways(); }
```