# Why comparing two longs with == returns false and when I cast to int or String it returns true?

Tags: java

I'm doing the following comparison:

```
atividade.getEscala().getId() == escala.getId()
```

and it returns `false` but if I type `atividade.getEscala().getId().intValue() == escala.getId().intValue()` then it returns `true`. It also returns `true` when I write `atividade.getEscala().getId().toString().equals(escala.getId().toString())`

I know by debugging that the content of both variables is the same ( `(java.lang.Long) 2` in display view ), then why does it returns false when I compare the longs with just `==`?

Comment: What happens if you use `.equals()` instead of `==`?

Comment: Integers have an internal pool for the lowest values, I'm not sure about longs. Your string question doesn't make too much sense

Comment: I edited because I had written the equals comparison wrong. it also return true when I use equals.

Comment: `Long` (capital) is a wrapper class, so it's an object and you're comparing references

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541636/compare-non-primitive-data-type-long-values-in-java

Comment: @Andreas this solves my doubts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `==` with two references, you are comparing whether the references are the same, not whether the contents of the objects referenced are the same.

This is made more complicated with auto-boxing caches. e.g. Longs between -128 and 127 are cached so you will get the same object every time.

e.g.

```
Long x = 100, y = 100;
System.out.println(x == y); // true, references are the same.

Long a = 200, b = 200; // values not cached.
System.out.println(a == b); // false, references are not the same.
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true, the objects referenced are equal
```

Comparing the intValue() is dangerous due to the risk of overflow.

```
Long c = -1, d = Long.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(c.equals(d)); // false
System.out.println(c.longValue() == d.longValue()); // false
System.out.println(c.intValue() == d.intValue()); // true, lower 32-bits are the same.
```

Comment: I see, my id is a `Long` not a `long`. Shoul I just use `.intValue()` then?

Comment: @StudioWorks best to use `.equals()` or if you have to `.longValue()` as two longs can be different but have the same `.intValue()`

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator compares identity, not equality. For equality, use `equals()`.

- identity: Two distinct variables share a common object. In other words, they point to the same underlying object, and thus reference the same memory address.
- equality: Two distinct objects represent the same thing. In other words, they are different objects, but have the same contents.

Answer (score 1):

When you use == operator on objects you compare memory reference values, not values. For primitives you compare values.

Answer (score 1):

If both values are Long, you need to compare them with equals(), as you do for all reference types. By calling intValue(), you're comparing int primatives, for which == works as you'd expect.