# How to compare two non-primitive Long in Java?

Tags: java

I'm searching for a method that can compare two non-primitive `Long` objects in Java. Something like this : `Longs.compare(Long x, Long y)`. As I didn't find anything on the web yet, I am wondering if a such library implement that.

So far, I compared them with `Long.compare(x, y)` but now I've realized that `x` and `y` can be null, so sometimes I can get a `NullPointerException`.

Do you know any library that can do that?

PS : My need is not the same as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541636/compare-non-primitive-long-values-127-and-128). I want to know if `x > y` not if `x == y`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare non-primitive Long values 127 and 128](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541636/compare-non-primitive-long-values-127-and-128)

Comment: @Mr.Robot Despite the similar summary line, I don't think this is a dupe of that question. That question is looking for equality comparisons only, and is basically about the confusion between `==` and `equals`. This question is asking for a `compareTo`-style comparison that includes nullity.

Comment: Keep using `compare`, just check for `null` before you do.

Comment: Test for `null`, and then use `Long.compare(x,y)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing for now. But I think it's too bad there isn't library that implement this...

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic.

Comment: You don't need an entire library for something so simple.

Comment: While it's true that you don't need a whole library just for this, if you already depend on a library that gives you this behavior (say, Guava or Apache Commons), you may as well use it. (In fact, pretty much _all_ of Guava is stuff for which you could argue, "you don't need a whole library just for this." But you add all of them together, and that library starts being worthwhile.)

Comment: There are already Guava and Apache Commons in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java SE 8 try:

```
Comparator<Long> nullsFirstLongComparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

or

```
Comparator<Long> nullsLastLongComparator = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is the [ObjectUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html) class from apache commons.  It's specifically designed to handle general `null`-safe comparison.

Its `compare()` method will never throw an exception based on `null` input, and instead just assumes that

> null is ... less than a non-null value.

So for instance:

```
    System.out.println(ObjectUtils.compare(null, null));                   // 0
    System.out.println(ObjectUtils.compare(new Long(1), null));            // 1
    System.out.println(ObjectUtils.compare(null, new Long(1)));            // -1
    System.out.println(ObjectUtils.compare(new Long(1), new Long(2)));     // -1
```

Comment: commons-lang3 3.12 do not have compare for Long.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is your best guide.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Please check the `public int compareTo(Long anotherLong)` method.

Comment: This will still throw NPEs, since all that `compareTo()` does is try compare `this.value` with `anotherLong.value`.

Comment: neither `null.compareTo(1L)` nor `1L.compareTo(null)` works (it will throw a null pointer exception)

Comment: AFAIK there is no built in API which does this. You could perhaps write your own version and check if either of the inputs is null?.

Answer (score 0):

The longhand answer is to check for nulls first, but you can also use Guava's [`Ordering<T>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html), which is an extension of `Comparator<T>` that also supports a fluent builder style:

```
Comparator<Long> nullsFirst = Ordering.natural().nullsFirst();
// there's also a nullsLast()
```