# Value equation of wrapper classes in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare 4 values in a program.

```
Long val1 = 127l;
Long val2 = 127l;
Long val3 = 128l;
Long val4 = 128l;
Log.e("XXXX",(val1==val2)+" "+(val3==val4));
```

This gives me `val1l == val2l` is `true` and `val3' == val4l` is `false`. What is the reason behind this output. I think it's coming because of the wrapper class. Please help me to clear this.

Comment: On a point of style: use `127L` rather than `127l`, because the latter looks a lot like `1271`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541636/compare-non-primitive-long-values-127-and-128

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149959/using-operator-in-java-to-compare-wrapper-objects