# How to compare Long type data in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to compare IMEI number in my phone with the data I declare, but the bug says: 'Operator == can not be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'long'
How do I fix that?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TelephonyManager manager;
    private Button button;
    TextView textView;
    String IMEI;
    long IMEI2 = 356261058647361;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        IMEI = manager.getDeviceId();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(IMEI == IMEI2){
                    textView.setText("IMEI NUMBER : " + IMEI);

                }else{
                    textView.setText("data IMEI and IMEI2 did not match");
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: use this >>>>IMEI .equals(IMEI2) after changing Long.parseLong(IMEI);

Comment: The fact that you're using `==` for strings should be the first sign that code is not correct

Comment: use Long IMEI2 = 356261058647361L; and use .equal() method instead of == 
see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541636/compare-non-primitive-long-values-127-and-128

Comment: works like a charm, thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java for long you need to declare like `long IMEI2 = 356261058647361L;`

you need to add '**L**' . refere : [Long type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6834049/8089770)

`Long.parseLong()`

> The `Long.parseLong()` static method parses the string argument as a
>   signed decimal long and returns a long value.

Use :

```
Long.parseLong(IMEI);
```

Use this way : `long tmp = Long.parseLong(IMEI);` before the if condition.

then in if :

```
if (tmp == IMEI2)
```

---

Reference: [Long.parseLong()](http://javadevnotes.com/java-string-to-long-examples)

Comment: @borneo Happy to help :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(IMEI2.equals(""+IMEI){
                    textView.setText("IMEI NUMBER : " + IMEI);

                }else{
                    textView.setText("data IMEI and IMEI2 did not match");
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(IMEI.equals(String.valueOf(IMEI2)){
    textView.setText("IMEI NUMBER : " + IMEI);
}else{
    textView.setText("data IMEI and IMEI2 did not match");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Datatype Long instead of long. Always use `L` at the end of your value while initiating Long/long datatype and check it using `equals`

```
Long IMEI;
Long IMEI2 = 356261058647361L;

IMEI = Long.valueOf(manager.getDeviceId());

if (IMEI2.equals(IMEI)) {
    textView.setText("IMEI NUMBER : " + IMEI);
} else {
    textView.setText("data IMEI and IMEI2 did not match");
}
```